# YouTube API V3 doesn't return all comments

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, comments, youtube-data-api

I have a problem with the YT API. Request to "commentThreads" doesn't return all top level comments. Random comments are omitted.

For example:

YT movie ID: 3VPlDKsVgUg

It's my request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=API_KEY&part=snippet,id&maxResults=100&videoId=3VPlDKsVgUg - response has 21 top level comments

On the YT are 37 top level comments (all comments with replies are 52).

Missing comments do not differ significantly from the others.

Has anyone had a similar problem? I was looking for solutions on the Internet, but did not find anything interesting.

Comment: I can confirm the same results. My only guess is the missing comment threads have a moderationStatus of 'heldForReview' or 'likelySpam' that can only be checked by an authorized request.

Comment: I checked it, and rather it is not a problem.

Comment: I am trying to get all comments (getting pages of threads, then getting pages of replies), I can only get about 4900 out of 7200. videoId = `BRI-A3vakVg`

Comment: Here is an answer, maybe helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546995/youtube-data-api-v3-commentthread-call-doesnt-give-replies-for-some-comment-th